# Meaning of "To take half"

Tags: meaning

In Eminem's song [Crazy in love](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/eminem/crazyinlove.html) there is the expression *never took half*:

> You're like the pillar that props me up
>
> The beam that supports me
>
> The b...h who never took half,
>
> The wife who never divorced me.

What does it (never took half) mean?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because song lyrics can have multiple meanings, especially if it's from the rap god.

Comment: Off topic -- request for literature interpretation/criticism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might mean she didn't try to get half your net worth (perhaps by marrying you without a prenup, and then divorcing you).

Answer (score 1):

Cathy Gartaganis is right; this refers to [alimony](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alimony), or each partner receiving half of their shared assets upon divorce. It's also the subject of Kanye West's *Gold Digger,* which features the lines

> If you ain't no punk, holla, "We want prenup!"
>   "We want prenup!" (Yeah!)
>   It's something that you need to have
>   Cause when she leave your ass she gonna **leave with half**

If you ever want to know what rap lyrics mean, look them up on [genius.com](http://genius.com/467950).